# How can I arrange labels and textboxes side by side on resize?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I am having issue with screen resizing. This code below looks fine on full screen, however if I resize my window just a smidgen it starts to look off and terrible. I went through the bootstrap 4 grid layout tutorial and it is giving me issue.

Currently it only looks like this in full screen;
From: [ 01/01/2010 ]   To: [ 12/18/2018]

The second the screen resizes it looks like this

From: [ 01/01/2010 ]       To:
 [ 12/18/2018]

If the screen resizes to anything other than full screen it needs to look like this and stay there until the smallest screen size.

From: [ 01/01/2010 ]
To:                                                                         [ 12/18/2018]

I know with the grid system it is based off large, medium, small, xtra small. However anything other than full screen to me is medium or lower.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <label for="fromUploadDate text-muted">From:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <kendo-datepicker></kendo-datepicker>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label for="toUploadDate text-muted">To:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <kendo-datepicker></kendo-datepicker>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: try to use inline block

Comment: You might need to provide a demo. Your datepicker might be complicating things.

Comment: Please, provide a demo code of what you have now, in a way that we can understand the context. The first thing that come into my mind is to use `col-md-3 col-6` classes on the divs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [should help](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) you out. You just need to add a little to the end of `col` using one of the options from the official Bootstraps documents. And `clearfix` should break up everything into 2 lines. For example:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-2">
  <label for="fromUploadDate text-muted">From:</label>
 </div>
 <div class="col-2">
  <kendo-datepicker></kendo-datepicker>
 </div>
 <div class="clearfix"></div>
 <div class="col-2">
  <label for="toUploadDate text-muted">To:</label>
 </div>
 <div class="col-2">
  <kendo-datepicker></kendo-datepicker>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Edit: 2018-12-20**

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row col-sm-7">
  <div class="col">
   <label for="fromUploadDate text-muted">From:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
   <kendo-datepicker></kendo-datepicker>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row col-sm-7">
  <div class="col">
   <label for="toUploadDate text-muted">To:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
   <kendo-datepicker></kendo-datepicker>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `col` is a valid Bootstrap class. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#equal-width

Comment: Ok I like the  <div class="w-100"></div> they have however, For full screen is there a way I can keep everything on one line and keep the To: and DateBox together? So if datebox moves then the To: label moves with it

Comment: @isherwood Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I know that `col` is valid, I just meant that it needs to be followed by something else, like `-sm` making `col-sm` or `5` making `col-5`. I've changed it above.

Comment: No, it doesn't. If you think that's needed here you should explain why.

Comment: Okay things seem to line up correctly when `row` is followed by something, like `col-sm-7` (`row col-sm-7`).